# Card dealing probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My text says the following:

> Probability that when dealing two cards, if the first card is an ace, then the second card is also an ace. Let B be the event that the first card is an ace, and let A be the event that the second card is an ace. Note that P(A)= P(B) = 1/13

Where did 1/13 come from? I know that there are 13 ranks for each of the 4 suits, but I would've guessed something like 1/52 and 1/51...

We need to figure out P(A and B) for which there are 52*51 sample points since we care about order with no replacement of cards. They say that the sample point where both cards are aces can happen 4*3=12 ways. I know the 4 comes from the 4 suits the Ace could be but where does 3 come from?

Comment: $\frac{4}{52} = \frac {1}{13}$  the probabilites that they have told you are only true if you don't have any information as to whether or not the other card is an ace.  Additionally the word 'then' in the first sentence is used in a confusing manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original $1/13$ comes because there are $4$ aces among the $52$ cards, so the chance of a given card being an ace is $4/52=1/13$.  For getting the first two cards aces, the probability that the first one is an ace is $4/52$ as before.  Given that the first is an ace, the chance the second is an ace is $3/51$ as there are $51$ cards left and $3$ of them are aces.

Comment: Thank you that's very clear. I want to understand the 4*3 in terms of points in a sample space. If there are 52*51 possible card pairs, how can I deduce that 4*3 of those pairs are both aces?

Comment: There are four choices for the first ace and for each one there are three choices remaining.  You can write out the twelve possibilities.  Just start with drawing the spade first, then you have ??? as choices for the second, and so on.

Comment: Also, How can we say that $P(A) = P(B) = \frac{4}{52} = \frac{1}{13}$ ? Wouldn't the probability of event $A$, that the second card is an ace, be reduced to $\frac{3}{51}$ ?

Comment: If you just say $P(A)$ it is the probability the second card is an ace regardless of the first card.

Comment: Oh okay thanks - still getting used to the language!